# removing parenthesis from extracted regex value

Tags: python, regex

Here is my input and result for regex:

```
temp2 = '(LEFT-WALL)(who)(is.v)(the)(di(rect)or.n)(of)(Inceptio)(RIGHT-WALL)'
print regex.findall(r'\([^\)\(]*+(?:(?R)[^\)\(]*)*+\)', temp2)
```

result :

```
  ['(LEFT-WALL)', '(who)', '(is.v)', '(the)', '(di(rect)or.n)', '(of)', '(Inceptio)', '(RIGHT-WALL)']
```

I want this sort of result:;

```
 ['LEFT-WALL', 'who', 'is.v', 'the', 'di(rect)or.n', 'of', 'Inceptio', 'RIGHT-WALL']
```

any change in regex?

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative without using regex you can do the job just with `str.split()` and `str.strip()` methods :

```
>>> [i.strip('()') for i in temp2.split(')(')]
['LEFT-WALL', 'who', 'is.v', 'the', 'di(rect)or.n', 'of', 'Inceptio', 'RIGHT-WALL']
```

Or with regex you can use [*look-around*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in your regex :

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\)\(|\)$)', temp2)
['LEFT-WALL', 'who', 'is.v', 'the', 'di(rect)or.n', 'of', 'Inceptio', 'RIGHT-WALL']
```

*Note* that the logic is simple you just need to match the string that is between open parenthesis `(` and a close parenthesis that followed by an open bracket `)(` .

Answer (score 1):

You need to match either strings that are between `(` and `)(`, or between `)(` and `)`. That way you avoid matching strings like `'(rect)'` in `'(di(rect)or.n)'`. You can do that by using [lookaround assertions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#lookahead%20assertion) since they don't consume the string searched.

**Lookahead assertion**:

> `(?=...)`
>       Matches if `...` matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. 
>   This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, `Isaac (?=Asimov)` will match `'Isaac '` only if it’s followed by `'Asimov'`.

**Positive lookbehind assertion**:

> `(?<=...)`
>       Matches if the current position in the string is preceded by a match for ... that ends at the current position. This is called a
>   positive lookbehind assertion. `(?<=abc)def` will find a match in
>   `abcdef`, since the lookbehind will back up 3 characters and check if
>   the contained pattern matches.

In the code below i use `re.VERBOSE` flag to make it more readable.

```
pattern = re.compile(r"""

(?<=  \(  )   .+?  (?=  \)\(  )   # Matches string after a '(' and before a ')('

|                                 # or...

(?<=  \)\(  )   .+?  (?=  \)  )   # Matches string after a ')(' and before a ')'    

""", re.VERBOSE)


print (re.findall(pattern, temp2))
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel you do not need any regex for the sample string you provided:

```
temp2 = '(LEFT-WALL)(who)(is.v)(the)(di(rect)or.n)(of)(Inceptio)(RIGHT-WALL)'
if temp2[0:1] == "(" and temp2[-1:] == ")":
    print temp2[1:-1].split(")(")
```

Output of the [sample program](http://goo.gl/xzA6hi):

```
['LEFT-WALL', 'who', 'is.v', 'the', 'di(rect)or.n', 'of', 'Inceptio', 'RIGHT-WALL']
```